# Cloud Explorer fails with "Unable to retrieve child resources"

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

How to fix this bug?

1. Open Cloud Explorer (logged in)
2. Open "Files" folder for some Azure Web App (former Azure Website)
3. Result:

> Cloud Explorer has encountered an unexpected error: Unable to retrieve
>   child resources.
>
> Details: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition
>   for 'requestNamespace'

I'm using:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Azure App Service Tools v2.9.6   14.0.21111.0
- Common Azure Tools   1.8
- Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.9.41104.6

Comment: any solution for your question.
please tell me solution if you have.

Comment: @PratikPatel Haven't found one yet. Just reload VS and it sometime helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was a permissions issue, mine was with a Cosmos Document DB database node.

I had my DevOps guy add me as a contributor to the IAM Azure role and it started working for me.   So check all the permissions, and it is the cloud so sometimes you have to give it time to propagate the changes too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when both [Azure Storage Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) and [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) trying to run at the same time. Try uninstall one or run only one at a time to solve the issue.

Have a look at [troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting?tabs=Windows%2C2004) might also help.